# Golang check if unmarshaled JSON value is nil

Tags: json, go, interface

When unmarshalling a string of json, using Golang's `json.Unmarshal()` function, I always unmarshal the string into a `map[string]interface{}` - *I'm not sure weather there is a more optimal way of decoding json.*

**To get to the point:**

Sometimes the json's unmarshalled type is `nil`, not `string` (or `int` etc.). This always throws a panic, saying:

> interface conversion: interface is nil, not int

How can I avoid this panic or check if the interface's type is `nil` or not?

**Example:**

Here is an example of my problem in action: https://play.golang.org/p/0ATzXBbdoS

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check if the key exist instead of letting it panic.

```
func keyExists(decoded map[string]interface{}, key string) {
    val, ok := decoded[key]
    return ok && val != nil
}

func main() {

jsonText := `{
        "name": "Jimmy",
        "age":  23
    }`

    var decoded map[string]interface{}

    if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(jsonText), &decoded); err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        os.Exit(0)
    }

    if keyExists(decoded, "name") {
        fmt.Println(decoded["name"].(string))
    }
    if keyExists(decoded, "age") {
        fmt.Println(decoded["age"].(float64))
    }
    if keyExists(decoded, "gender") {
        fmt.Println(decoded["gender"].(int))
    }
}
```

Also, this is far from being optimal if you know what your json will look like. As specified in the documentation, you can unmarshal it directly into a struct:

```
type Human struct {
    Name string
    Age int
    Gender int
}

func main() {
    jsonText := `{
        "name": "Jimmy",
        "age":  23
    }`

    decoded := Human{}

    if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(jsonText), &decoded); err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        os.Exit(0)
    }

    fmt.Println(decoded.Name)
    fmt.Println(decoded.Age)
    fmt.Println(decoded.Gender)
}
```

Comment: I have a question about defining a struct and extracting the json into it. If I were to have some json looking like: { "name": "Jimmy", "traits": { "age": 23, "gender": 0 } } ... How would I define the values "age" and "gender" in a struct? Here is a base of where you can work from to answer my question: https://play.golang.org/p/TyXbrFAtGo

Comment: Make a nested struct `Traits` which contains `age` and `gender`. Also, read the documentation of the [encoding/json](https://godoc.org/encoding/json#Marshal) package

Comment: Thank you for such a quick reply. For anyone who is interested, here is how I solved my problem: https://play.golang.org/p/mq5XL47msM